# Navigation Drawer in bottomappbar android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[image]

```
class BottomNavigationDrawerFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment(), 
   NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottomsheet, container, false)
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item : MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Bottom Navigation Drawer menu item clicks
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav1 -> context!!.toast("oneeeeee")
            R.id.nav2 -> context!!.toast("twoooooo")
            R.id.nav3 -> context!!.toast("threeeee")

            return true
        }
        // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
        // For example, swap
    }
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
        // For example, swap
    }
}

// This is an extension method for easy Toast call
fun Context.toast(message: CharSequence) {
    val toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 600)
    toast.show()
}
```

What I want to achieve is something given in image. I want to make a `navigation drawer` in bottom app bar. Above code doesn't work and it tells unresolved reference type `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`. What is the error in my code?

Comment: use bottom navigation drawer

Comment: i want to use bottom app bar .Cant i use navigation drawer in bottom sheet with bottomapp bar ?

Comment: no you can not both are different

Comment: look at the image.In left side below we have a drawer.when we click it it will open a bottom sheet which will have navigation.Same situatation like google task.

Comment: ya this is only a navigation icon

Comment: could i use a bottom sheet which have navigation drawer in it ,after i clicked that navigation icon

Comment: do you know how to make customize navigation drawer?

Comment: Yes.i  just asking about error in code which handles menu item clicking

Answer (score 2):

you should add a drawer icon in your `bottomAppbar`, then use a `bottomsheet` for the drawer.

for your drawer you have two choices:

**1**- go with google standards and add drawer items in menu folder (seems you dont want this)

**2**- replace a fragment in your bottom sheet, in this way you can customize your fragment and do whatever you like

-------------------  **replace a fragment in your bottom sheet**  -------------

***your activity.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

                 <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/menu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
            </FrameLayout>

  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***your  Activity.java***

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
FragmentNavigation.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private View bottomSheet;
    private BottomSheetBehavior<View> behavior;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        FrameLayout bottomSheetLayout = (FrameLayout) 
        findViewById(R.id.menu);

        FragmentNavigation fragmentNavigation = new FragmentNavigation();

        androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(bottomSheetLayout.getId(), 
        fragmentNavigation, "k");

        fragmentTransaction.commit();


        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) 
        findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

***your fragment navigation***

```
    public class FragmentNavigation extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
    private String descriptions;

    public FragmentNavigation () {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

***your fragment_navigation.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:elevation="6dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:text="here is the navigation menu"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"/>



      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you tell me that what does it mean to reply fragment in bottom sheet  ? and how it will achieve same as navigation drawer work

Comment: your bottom sheet is a blank layout that you could put items in it, right?
when you replace a fragment in your bottomsheet actually your fragment opens in shape of a bottomsheet. then when you open your bottomsheet you will see your fragment content. as simple as that. if you still didnt get that let me know

Comment: Seems quite confusing!!

Answer (score 1):

See this code it has a navigationIcon attribute but you can use as a bottom app bar. If you need navigation drawer on this click then you have to customize by our own.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
  android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  app:elevation="5dp"
  android:elevation="5dp"
  app:fabAttached="true"
  app:fabCradleDiameter="0dp"
  app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
  app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
  app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
  app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_menu"/>
```

In res>menu>bottom_bar_menu, change showAsAction to always or ifRoom, put an icon for action_settings and remove orderInCategory

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="" />
    <item
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_archieve"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bottom_bar_hamburger" // navigation icon
        android:title="@string/action_archieve"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

in java :

```
BottomAppBar bar = (BottomAppBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
setSupportActionBar(bar);

bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Handle the navigation click by showing a BottomDrawer etc.
    }
});

bar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle actions based on the menu item
        return true;
    }
});
```

Reference Link : https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/

Comment: i want to know what wrong in my code ?why it tells unresolved type navigation listener? how can i handle drawer menu item clicking with kotlin?

Comment: does second function will handle clicking event of drawer in bottomsheet

Comment: @VipinDubey yes all menu items like navigation icon also

Comment: check I have added a reference link in my answer

Comment: I have added all things in my answer Please check again

Answer (score 0):

```
bottom_bar.replaceMenu(R.menu.bottomappbar_menu)
    bottom_bar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.app_bar_copy -> {

            }
            R.id.app_bar_fav -> {

            }
            R.id.app_bar_tra -> {

            }
            else -> {

            }
        }
         true
    }
```

Just add code in fragment to handle menu item.